# why does my dell latitude e6520 have internet in install but not after

Tags: wireless, dell

Hey all I installed Ubuntu 13.04 x64 last night had internet in the installer by going to additional drivers and enabling brodcom (sic) driver but after install it won't let me enable it. I have no Ethernet driver ether..

PS not home right noe but when I am I'll upload full name of my wirelrss

Thanks in advanced

In additional drivers its called broadcom BC 43228 802.11a/b/g/n

Like I said I activated it on the live disk but can't activate it noe and my Ethernet isn't working eather

Comment: Aight got it working had to use easytether on my android phone to get internet to my PC then installed the broadcom driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable the broadcom drivers, you have to have an internet connection first. So, you will definitely need an ethernet connection to do so.

I'm not certain, but perhaps the live CD includes the broadcom drivers on its disk, but doesn't install them as part of the process? I've only rarely seen something work in the Live CD but fail to work in a proper install.